# Git fetch only "namespaced" remote tags?

Tags: git

I am working on a repo with a naming convention to separate isolated projects with top branch namespaces, such as:

```
A1 - A2 - A3 - A4 - ... - An   projectA/*

B1 - B2 - B3 - B4 - ... - Bn   projectB/*
```

When I config my local git for projectA as below:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/projectA/*:refs/remotes/origin/projectA/*
```

My expectation is as [git-fetch manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) says about the default behavior: *tags that point at objects that are downloaded from the remote repository are fetched and stored locally.*

That is, if I fetch `projectA/*`, only tags pointing to A1, A2, ..., or An should be fetched. However say a `projectB/blah` tag pointing commit `Bn` is fetched to the local when I run `git fetch origin` on the local projectA git.

I am totally confused. Is there something I do wrong? What does the "default behavior" mean and what is the difference between `git fetch` with and without `--tags`?

Answer (score 2):

Without `--tags`, `git fetch` literally checks each tag reference to see if its target SHA-1 is going to be fetched.

The whole `fetch` operation starts by, in essence, running `git ls-remote` (try it and see what it produces).  Then, if you have not specified `--tags`, it runs through the list of all refs (in a routine named `find_non_local_tags` in [`builtin/fetch.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/fetch.c).  Those that start with `refs/tags/` are tags, so it proceeds to see if those tags refer to objects that will be fetched.  If the object will be fetched, the tag is added to the list of refs to update.

With `--tags`, however, the same code simply adds `tag_refspec` to the ref-specs it is to fetch.  This is defined in [`remote.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/remote.c) and is basically a pre-parsed form of `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*`.

Note that throughout this whole process, tags are simply "references that start with the literal prefix `refs/tags/`".  There are no "namespaced tags": the tag name space is the entire universe of names starting with `refs/tags/`.  What git calls "remote branches" or "remote-tracking branches" *do* have separate sub-name-spaces: they are all in `refs/remotes/` but those for remote `origin` are specifically kept in `refs/remotes/origin/`, while those for remote `bob` are in `refs/remotes/bob`.  So I'm not really sure what you mean by "namespaced remote tags" in the question.

Comment: In my case the branch namespaces refer to totally separate projects. For example branches `projectA/*` and `projectB/*` must have no intersection, and a tag `projectB/blah` must not be any commit in any of the `projectA/*` branches. Therefore when I fetch `projectA/*`, I expect that I only get the tags on the `projectA/*` lines, i.e. the `projectA/*` tags.

Comment: So you mean you have, e.g., `refs/tags/projectB/foo` pointing to commit `1234567...` (all on the server) which is never fetched (on the client), but `refs/tags/projectB/foo` gets created (on the client) anyway?

Comment: It's definitely not supposed to.  What does `git ls-remote` say for `refs/tags/projectB/foo` (does it have multiple lines, with unpeeled and peeled refs, for instance)?

Comment: When I run `git ls-remote` on the local project A git I get a list like: `HEAD`, `refs/heads/projectA/master`, `refs/heads/master`, `refs/heads/projectB/master`, `refs/heads/projectB/XXX`, `refs/tags/projectB/YYY`. And `refs/tags/projectB/YYY` points to the commit exactly as `refs/heads/projectB/master`. Excuse me for not understanding what "(un)peeled" actually mean.

Comment: (Peeled vs unpeeled refers to annotated tags; if you don't have those, you never see this special case.)  OK, so, if you delete tag `projectB/YYY` from the client and then run `git fetch` (without `--tags`) on the client, it *should not* re-create the tag, since it's not bringing over the commit with that SHA-1 ID.  (But if you ever brought the tag over in the past, it will persist until you delete it.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. So I *should not* get `projectB/YYY` recreated when I fetch `projectA/*`, right? And my problem is that it DOES recreate. Confirmed with a newly cloned repo (only changed the settings of `remote.origin.fetch`).

Comment: OK, that implies there's a bug in git, as it's really not supposed to do that.  If you can construct a small self-contained example (two repos, some instructions/shell-scripts for configuring the second one and doing the fetch, etc) and send it to the git mailing list, someone might go to fix it.